# Set file with no .extension

Tags: c#, database, file-extension

I'm using the following code to trim the file  extensions  of some items . It latter pulls off a database. It seems database is not pulling the ".". In short I want file.ext to be turned to file but the closest Ive gotten is file "." which isn't working for me

```
string linkWithoutExtension = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(path, "");
```

Thanks for any help.

Edit
Ok I changed it to the following but now its giving me an even weirder problem. Its renaming the path. So instead of it being (site.com/type/subtype/type1/video/videoname.) like I got before I now get (site.com/type/subtype/elsewhere/nothere/videoname).

```
string linkWithoutExtension = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` method so

```
string path = @"C:\Users\UN\Documents\message.msg";
string linkWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
```

As Pointed out by peter i forgot about the original directory so you can use `Path.Combine` and `Path.GetDirectoryName(path)` as shown in peters answer

Comment: This returns only "message", not the full path and file name without extension: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx

Comment: @Peter added mention, although he did say in the question `In short I want file.ext to be turned to file`, I just chose a bad example

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.IO;

string linkWithoutExtension = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path));
```